# ReactJS Toggle Full Screen on Screen Orientation Change Event

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, screen-orientation

Using the JS Fullscreen API, I am attempting to toggle fullscreen based on screen orientation. The current code allows for the `<video />` to enter fullscreen mode when changing orientation from portrait to landscape, however, `<video />` will not exit fullscreen when returning to portrait mode as the orientation `change` event will not fire while in full screen. How can this be remedied?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handle_videoFullScreen = _ => {
        const { type } = window.screen.orientation
        const video = document.querySelector('video')

        if (type.startsWith('portrait')) {
            document.exitFullscreen()
        } else {
            video.requestFullscreen().catch(console.log)
        }
    }
    window.screen.orientation.addEventListener(
        'change',
        handle_videoFullScreen
    )
    return _ => {
        window.screen.orientation.removeEventListener(
            'change',
            handle_videoFullScreen
        )
    }
})
```